# What is the best architecture / data structure for detecting changes in state of data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on a data structure with moving devices. I already added geohashes (open location code). And I'm able to use where >= geohash_low and where <= geohash_high to search within an area.

If I look this up, I get results within (roughly) this area. The next step is to look back per device when they entered or left the area. If I look back, I can determine this easily, but the next step is to determine it at the moment that a new message is placed in the database.

My first idea would be to create a copy of every incoming message at device/latest. And then monitor with a onChange cloud function the changes. And then determine if the change was going from inside to outside an area or the otherway around.

But this architecture will add an extra write operation (to latest message) at every incoming message. And it will add an extra read operation (onChange).

Another approach would be to do an additional read at every incoming message to read a latest state of inside or outside an area. And compare that with the current position. That would 'cost' only an extra read at every incoming message. If the state needs to be changed, then perform an extra write.

Basically the problem is that I need to manage a state, while functions are stateless.
Any other thoughts...

Thanks a lot for your thoughts.

Comment: Did you need real time update?

Comment: It seems you need two points.  The last point and the current point and you want to know when a transition occurs where the last point was outside and the current is inside and also when the last point was inside and the current is outside.  You can't seem to perform this determination without at least these two points.  You either maintain state for each device (eg. a datastore such as GCP DataStore or MemStore) or else your device provides its own last and current with each new publish.

Comment: ... you are likely going to want to store additional data.  For example, if your "device" is close to your boundary, you might want to throttle transitions if they are bouncing in and out which means you might want to also record the last time a transition was "determined" so as to not publish transitions too quickly (this is a guess on my part).